# Visual Studio 2015 xamarin cannot deploy

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

Every time I try to debug the application that is preset in the android application tab, which has to have no errors, I get this message:

> ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>   ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

I got the same error before so I tried removing all the program (Visual Studio and Xamarin) and reinstalling it.

so I newly downloaded and installed visual studio 2015 professional and also included the Xamarin, but I always get the error above.

Alongside this problem, I cannot get the preview of the application when I click the 'References' in the 'Solution Explorer' tab.  What are the possible cause for the above said problems and how can I fix it?

Comment: Right click your Solution =>Configuration Manager  and check if Deploy is checked in your Solution.Droid project.

Comment: go up in Output is there some Exceptions?

Comment: Please also provide a diagnostic build output in your question:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27515/how-to-obtain-diagnostic-build-logs (XS) and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/09/29/475157.aspx (VS)

The deploy is actually failing, not skipping. Thus it's not a problem with your Configuration Manager.